# How to fix world environment texture background view when it is viewed in circle rather than in normal view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using blender version 2.77, and I try to set the world environment in cycle render. At some reason when I use the background with the environment texture, the background is bend in circle view rather than the normal picture view. What did I do wrong. How do I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: My node set up is World output  > Background > Environment Texture (Single Image, Color,Linear and Equirectangular).

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46517/trouble-viewing-whole-hdr-image-as-cycles-world/46519#46519

Answer (score 0):

The world environment image is a spherical view by default, you can't change that.

If you are simply trying to set up a flat background image for your scene, I'd recommend the **Import Image as Plane** addon that comes with Blender.

Just enable it in your User Preferences, and then you can import an image and it will automatically create a material and map the image to the plane. Then you can position it in the background of your scene.

Comment: I did that, but it still has the same result. I follow the tutorial step by step. tutorial render show nice background environment background, but my background completely circle.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. Don't use the World Texture, just use a simple image plane in your scene.