# HDRI scaling issues?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri

So, I get it that I'm probably missing something here, but this is an incredibly frustrating issue with HDRI's that I...well, I can't find how to fix.[image]

I tried mapping, changing the scale of the HDRI and...I'm just stuck.  The image above was created from a tutorial on HDRI's, downloaded the sample image and it looks nothing (obviously) like the tutorial.

People make it look easy.  Just plug the HDRI into the environment node and it'll work, they said...

Here's the node setup of the above mentioned cube.

[image]

I know this is some setting I'm over looking because this was created with the default scene and literally just adding the HDRI.  It happens no matter what HDRI I use and no matter what scene.

Small addition:  the camera is in perspective mode, not ortho.

Further, I can't add the HDRI due to site limitations, but it's supposed to be an interior room.  Hard to tell because it's so stretched out...but yeah...any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your environment looks like it's working but what nodes are you using for the cubes material? Have you added a node that will provide some sort of reflection on it? such as a glossy node. Is the glossy nodes roughness value near zero or right up at one.

Comment: Other than looking like a low res image the environment seems correct. Where did you download the HDRi from? Is it a 360 image? What are you expecting to see in the 3D viewport. Please read this post: [viewing whole HDR as world](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46517/trouble-viewing-whole-hdr-image-as-cycles-world/46519#46519) and let us knew if that is your issue.

Comment: The HDRI is from this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4IN4V1SM-A

And that first image is not from the 3D viewport but the final render.  If I could upload the HDRI, you'd be able to see what's terrible about this, but the site won't let me.  The material of the cube is default.  I don't really mind if it reflects or not.  I'd rather the HDRI not be pixelated and stretched out so much that you can't make out what it is.

Comment: And I just wanted to add, I started to look into this because I tried to use a "Space" Hdri and the stars (little white dots) were huge and pixelated.  So I tried the tutorial above to see if I overlooked something...but it's still taking the HRDI and stretching it out, but scaling the object doesn't help and scaling the HRDI makes it worse.

Comment: As a side note, when posting screenshots please post them in higher resolution and without distortions. It's kind of hard to read it as of now.

Comment: Yeah, the second image was rushed (ctrl V in paint), but I just wanted to show that the nodes were setup appropriately.  Will edit and add a better one later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HDRI is 2048×1024 only. It could be enough for lighting or reflections but not for a visible environement image (or for a very low res render).
You'll find links to HDRIs (and other ressources) [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15358/11431).

Comment: So...the HDRI needs to be bigger?  A lot bigger?

Comment: If you want it to be visible in your render, yes. The image you've posted is 960px × 540, that's 1/2 size of your HDRI that has to cover 360°.