# Background World Texture (Cycles) No Render

Tags: node-editor, world

[image: My Nodes,]

Using Nodes with Cycles Render

Background only shifts hues with adjustments. Thank you for any input. :)

Comment: Change to perspective view to see the background buy clicking numpad 5

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46517/trouble-viewing-whole-hdr-image-as-cycles-world/46519#46519