# What might be causing this blocky shading on my model?

Tags: rendering, shaders

I have a model that I sculpted and retopologised in another application, and then imported the retopologised mesh into Blender with a normal map.

The mesh is around 9200 verts, and I have smooth shading turned on.

I am getting an odd shading artifact in the form of jagged edges: 
[image]

While the surface is not perfect, it seems more than smooth enough that this artifact should not be happening.

The object has a normal map applied (baked from the high quality sculpt), but I can turn that off an get the same thing:

[image]

Here is a shot of the wireframe:

[image]

Is this abnormal like I think it is? What might be causing it? I have checked the mesh for everything I can think of.

**EDIT:** I have made the file available here (20M, sorry): [image]

Comment: "I have checked the mesh for everything I can think of." Does that include double faces/vertices and/or inverted normals?
That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: Remove doubles, make normals consistent and non-manifold geometry. Check, check and check.

Comment: Can you share the model?

Comment: Any edges marked sharp or crease or anything? That can be hidden or obscured by UV seams, check the N panel for vis options.

Comment: Does that show up if rotating model and looking at it from another view points? It could be terminator problem although I barely think it is. Try also enabling Smooth shading in Edit mode with all faces selected; maybe those still use Flat shading.

Comment: Not a cycles user but check shadows, I've seen something similar with low sample shadows sometimes in Internal.

Comment: Cheers everyone for the replies. I will post the model when I get into work. I will also double check for all the things suggested.

Comment: I have made the file available and edited my original post. I couldn't find any of the additional suggested faults. Maybe it is the terminator problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mesh is fine. The primary cause of the geometric shadow is the texture co-ordinates you have given the HDR environment. The simple HDR setup here...

[image]

...results in a smooth shadow.

[image]

As reference: [Trouble Viewing Whole HDR Image as cycles world](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46517/trouble-viewing-whole-hdr-image-as-cycles-world/46519#46519)

The PBR node you have added obvious effects the edges...

[image]

Comment: I'd like to add that this Problem is celled the "Terminator Error/Problem" and can also happen in other render engines. This error isn't just caused by HDRIs as it can also happen in other situations, often when the model has a subsurface Modifier on it. Usually the best solution is just applying the Subsurface Modifier.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right, in that the HDRI setup (which is just the Gaffer HDRI manager setup) was severely highlighting the problem, but I also agree with @NilsEisen in that this problem seems to be more than just that. I can see the bad shading with different HDRIs and even no HDRI at all. I have enough understanding of the issue to go one now and can experiment for better results.

Comment: I believe Campbell Barton (One of the main Blender Contributors) was saying that this is a hard issue to tackle but is in the process of being fixed or at least reduced.