# Hdri sky background too close?

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, light, lighting

I'm using an image for the background, but I only see a blue sky and not the clouds in the bottom of the image near the horizon. It feels like the background image is too close? And in the world tab the preview is just blue. Should I not see the clouds also?

If I create a scen that are 10x10 meter or 100x100 meter or 1000x1000 meter in size, how does Blender set the correct scale or distance between the scene and the background?

I can rotate the background, but can't find any clouds. And I have tested different settings in the Environment Texture node, but all I can see is blue background or very close to the sun. I get this problem often with this type of images, and I don't know what I am doing wrong? Have I missed some kind of settings?

Other types of hdri images, that look spherical, I have no problem with. But this image looks more ordinary. Preciate some help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: To preview the hdri in the viewport enable World Background in the Display rollout on the Properties shelf, in order to check where are those clouds actually.

Comment: When you map using equirectangular you have to imagine a giant sphere that surrounds the scene and your image gets projected from the center. Your clouds are likely at the bottom of the scene. In my opinion it makes no sense to use equrectangular if the image contains no ground information. Try other forms of projection. Read this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46517/trouble-viewing-whole-hdr-image-as-cycles-world/46519#46519

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at this anatomy of an HDRI image:

[image]

This is how things will be mapped. So your clouds are mapped below horizon.

The texture's aspect ratio should be 2:1. Anything else and things will be placed in wrong places unless you correct with mapping vectors (correcting epirectangular mapping could be tricky).

Looks like what you have is just the top hemisphere, but you are mapping it onto both hemispheres. The easiest fix is to edit the image itself and add the bottom by extending the canvas with black.

Comment: OK, but is there no way to use this kind of image as a background and also see the clouds? Why are there so many images likes this, if they are not usefull?

Comment: @3D-kreativ There is a way correcting with mapping math, but that is not that easy. The easiest method is adding the missing bottom part (with black). These cropped images are maybe useful in photoshop in matte painting, but not as hdri.